# How to implement such style UI?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I want to write some shareware and I love the GUI style in the following image:

[image: UI style sample]
<sub>(source: [batchimageconverter.com](http://www.batchimageconverter.com/images/index.jpg))</sub>

Who knows how to imp such style? I think maybe it uses some UI library, who knows whas is the UI library? I want to use C++ to write the program.

Comment: Ohh c'mon, that application is just hilarious. `imagemagick.dll`, 'nuff said.

Comment: It's not ImageMagick. I know the library, it's a image processing library, not regarding UI

Comment: I was saying that that application is a joke, it's just a frontend for ImageMagick, I wasn't saying it was that UI library.

Comment: Oh, and that application is illegal too(imagemagick licensing terms): _"include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes ImageMagick software;
provide clear attribution to ImageMagick Studio LLC for any distributions that include ImageMagick software."_ None of that is in the application.

Comment: Although it's simple, but I think it's useful. Somebody may needs such program...

Answer (score 2):

It's [almdev](http://www.almdev.com/)'s BusinessSkinForm/DynamicSkinForm with the [Laconic](http://www.almdev.com/prods/skins/laconic.htm) skin.

[image]

I wouldn't recommend using it, but you decide.

Comment: `I wouldn't recommend using it` -- Why?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: AFAIK there are better, more mature GUI libraries out there.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've tagged this as mfc, however if you wanted to be portable - you could look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/). It's not a specific theme - if that's what you are after, but I should imagine it's fairly straight foward to style..

Comment: I'm still confused that if it's legal to write shareware with QT and then to sell the software?

Comment: @softempire, read the terms of the LGPL...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a nice, portable and powerful GUI for C++, I'd recommend using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ Builder (fully compatible C++ compiler), there are quite a few VCL skin libraries that you can use to change the look and feel easily. Or you can do your own by handling the paint events for the components in low level.